# redirect in next js axios response

Tags: redirect, axios, next.js

i have a next js application. in dashboard page, i have a getserversideprops and before sending data to client, i should examinate user is admin of not. for this, i have axios and i want in axios catch, page redirected to home page.

```
axios.get(`https://URL/api/user-is-admin`, {headers: { authtoken: userCookie }})
    .then(d=>console.log("is admin"))
    .catch(e=>{
        return {
           redirect: {
              permanent: false,
              destination: "/login",
           },
           props: {},
     };
    })
```

but it not work. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

as the official next js docs said, you should return without props when you want to redirect. it works for me. hope it can help.
the official docs for this problem is here https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```